# Margin attribute displaying incorrectly on Android 4.4 Webview

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I work on an Android application developed using Phonegap, so most of my UI is done through Javascript/CSS/HTML. I have been making some UI changes to the app to make it more usable and also to make the code more maintainable. I've run into a bit of a snag though, on Android 4.4 the CSS `margin` attribute is not working properly for one of my views. Here are the images showing the disparity:

Android 4.1
[image: Android 4.1]

Android 4.4
[image: Android 4.4]

As you can see it looks like the margins in 4.4 are being squashed together. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yorLro7/) with my code:

```
<style>
.grid_parent {
    width:800px;
    height:8.5em;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    border:1px solid;
}
.grid_row {
    text-align:center;
    clear:left;
}
.grid_first_row {
    margin:1% 5%;
}
.grid_second_row {
    margin:1% 3.33%;
}
.grid_item {
    display:table;
    float:left;
    width:10%;
}
.grid_button {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60%;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="grid_parent">
        <div class="grid_row">
            <div class="grid_item grid_first_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_first_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_first_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_first_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_first_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_row">
            <div class="grid_item grid_second_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_second_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_second_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_second_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_second_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item grid_second_row">
                <img class="grid_button" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/18/check-box-outline-blank-512.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I suspect that it is due to Android 4.4 using a [new Webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html), but it seems like that is the wrong behavior. Am I wrong? How can I resolve this? Currently I am using `padding` for Android 4.4 but I would like to unify the styles for pre-KitKat and post-KitKat versions since `padding` doesn't quite center my icons like `margin` does.